# Webcasting/Broadcasting using VB.NET, MYSQL and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, mysql, vb.net, binaryfiles

I am currently working on my project webcasting, my concept is to capture the desktop of the host computer as an image/jpeg file and save it to the database, by having a common database VB.NET and ASP.NET can connect. And lastly, get the image/images from the database and render it to ASP.NET.

1.) VB.NET -> capture image 
2.) MYSQL  -> write image as BLOB
3.) ASP.NET-> binary write to web page

My problem is that the pictures that is rendered on to ASP.NET is choppy and flickery, do you know any way or method that i can eliminate these problem and  provide a smoother picture animation as a result without sacrificing equipment performance.?????

I would really appreciate any tip or suggestion.,. (^_^).,

---

here is the way i output pictures on the webpage:

If dr.HasRows Then

```
dr.Read()
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"   'gets or sets the type of output stream
Response.BinaryWrite(dr.Item("file")) 'writes a stream of binary characters to the http output stream
```

Else

I set 1 second to refresh the page, but the more I refresh the page, the more flicker i get.

Comment: This is almost certainly a problem with the way the images are output, can you add detail on how the output to the web page is done?

Comment: I query first to the database, then,
If dr.HasRows Then
   dr.Read()
   Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"   'gets or sets the type of output stream
   Response.BinaryWrite(dr.Item("file"))           'writes a stream of binary characters to the http output stream
endIf

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a pseudo-screen recorder with a realtime view?

If so, with the architecture of going from a Screen Capture to DB and render back out to an ASP.NET web application, there are so many layers waiting on each other to complete there that you're not going to get a really smooth view.

What I'd suggest is taking a look at how LogMeIn does this (www.logmein.com) - some kind of active object will need to be launched (WinForms app, ActiveX control, Silverlight app, etc) that establishes a direct connection to the "source" PC; that's the only way you can 'stream' images to the client and provide a reasonable experience.

At minimum, you will need to do something in AJAX to background-refresh the image and then smoothly replace it on the ASP.NET front end, or create an active executable that will establish a direct stream or poll the database for you. Hope that helps somewhat...

Comment: Yes., that is my goal, to create a pseudo-screen recorder with a realtime view / webcast,.
actualy I had got the concept of my project on that site ,. I had already tried it,. ,. but I cannot find the actual tools/softwares that ws used in order to do webcasting,.